# Same height for all containers - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with aligning all the containers in the given example. I would like them to adapt to the height of the largest container.

I have already tried several dozen ways and nothing **h-100** helps, unfortunately.

I am giving you a link to the example as it is supposed to look like and it looks like a design designed by a graphic designer - https://prnt.sc/vnwn38

```css
.comment__container{
background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="comment__header text-center">
                        <h2>Komu pomogłam</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="comment__container">
                                <div class="comment__container-text">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, rerum, impedit. Nihil, corrupti. Enim, voluptatibus, omnis. Enim tempore atque aperiam perspiciatis placeat? Autem corporis,</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__container-author text-right">
                                    <p>- Joanna</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="comment__container">
                                <div class="comment__container-text">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, rerum, impedit. Nihil, corrupti. Enim, voluptatibus, omnis. Enim tempore atque aperiam perspiciatis placeat? Autem corporis,Autem corporis, Autem corporis, Autem corporis,</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__container-author text-right">
                                    <p>- Martyna</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="comment__container">
                                <div class="comment__container-text">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, rerum, impedit. Nihil, corrupti. Enim, voluptatibus, omnis. Enim tempore atque aperiam perspiciatis placeat? Autem corporis, beatae iure! Voluptates quam numquam nam corporis laborum provident aperiam, minus exercitationem dolorum, dolorem error amet, suscipit minima porro voluptate nesciunt a sed sequi fugit, rem.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__container-author text-right">
                                    <p>- Aleksandra</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="comment__container">
                                <div class="comment__container-text">
                                    <p>Bardzo miły i profesjonalny kontakt. Dziękuję bardzo Pani Ewo za pomoc! Polecam! </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__container-author text-right">
                                    <p>- Monika</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="comment__container">
                        <div class="comment__container-text">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, rerum, impedit. Nihil, corrupti. Enim, voluptatibus, omnis. Enim tempore atque aperiam perspiciatis placeat? Autem corporis, beatae iure! Voluptates quam numquam nam corporis laborum provident aperiam, minus exercitationem dolorum, dolorem error amet, suscipit minima porro voluptate nesciunt a sed sequi fugit, rem.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, rerum, impedit. Nihil, corrupti. Enim, voluptatibus, omnis. Enim tempore atque aperiam perspiciatis placeat? Autem corporis, beatae iure! Voluptates quam numquam nam corporis laborum provident aperiam, minus exercitationem dolorum, dolorem error amet, suscipit minima porro voluptate nesciunt a sed sequi fugit, rem.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment__container-author text-right">
                            <p>- tata Łukasz</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```